# Can I use Javascript Closures here instead of a global variable?

Tags: javascript, closures

Current setup:

```
var placeId;
function selectPlace(place) {
    $('#selectPlace').html('Selected Place: <b>' + place.Name + '</b>');
    $('#map').hide(400);
    placeId = place.Id;
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#postMessage').click(function() {
        alert("PlaceId: " + placeId);
    });
});
```

Can/should I be using closures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems like what you're looking for is this:

```
function selectPlace(place) {
  if(!place){
    return selectPlace.placeId;
  }else{
    $('#selectPlace').html('Selected Place: <b>' + place.Name + '</b>');
    $('#map').hide(400);
    selectPlace.placeId = place.Id;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#postMessage').click(function() {
    alert("PlaceId: " + selectPlace());
  });
});
```

This isn't using a closure, it just stores the last assigned ID on the function object. Then you'd return the value if they don't use the function as a setter. If you wanted to use a closure to do the same thing, it would look a lot like the example above:

```
(function(){
  var placeId;

  window.selectPlace = function(place) {
    if(!place){
      return placeId;
    }else{
      $('#selectPlace').html('Selected Place: <b>' + place.Name + '</b>');
      $('#map').hide(400);
      placeId = place.Id;
    }
  }
})();
```

By the way, the easiest way to spot a closure is if a function has variables in it that haven't been declared with `var` inside of the current function, but have been in some other function it sits inside. As you can see above, the variable `placeId` isn't declared inside of the `selectPlace` function, meaning that the `selectPlace` function is a closure that uses the `placeId` variable.

Comment: Very cool.  Yes, I'm guessing I wasn't needing a closure, just trying to steer away from using a global (heard they was bad).  No idea why I couldn't think of this but thanks for adding it!

Comment: Instead of alert("PlaceId: " + placeId()); did you mean alert("PlaceId: " + selectPlace());?

Answer (score 6):

It seems a reasonable thing to do, based on the context, you can easily do it by substituting your code with a function expression a la:

```
 (function(){
     var placeId;
     // It looks like you want selectPlace to be a global function?
     // hence i'm using assignment of a function expression here
     selectPlace = function (place) { 
         $('#selectPlace').html('Selected Place: <b>' + place.Name + '</b>');
         $('#map').hide(400);
         placeId = place.Id;
     }

     $(document).ready(function()
     {
         $('#postMessage').click(function() {
             alert("PlaceId: " + placeId);
         });
     });
 })();
```

Comment: I just don't think I get it then (closures).  I thought I could use them to essentially not have a var placeId and instead of something like selectPlace() return a place.Id instead.

Comment: Something like: 

selectPlace = function (place) { 
   $('#selectPlace').html('Selected Place: <b>' + place.Name + '</b>');
   $('#map').hide(400);
   return place.Id;
 }

$('#postMessage').click(function() {
   alert("PlaceId: " + selectPlace());
  });

Comment: Which doesn't work :P

I'm also not sure how your example is better than my code?  Not trying to sound like a butt, but I really just don't know.  I'm not a javascript person so not sure how doing it this way would help or be better?

Comment: without full context of what you're doing i can't be sure of your intent, but the use of a closure in the case (that of the function expression) is to scope placeId, and thus prevent it from polluting the global scope.